# Newest zero-answer C# questions search misbehaving

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

Today my trusty search for newest zero-answer C# questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20%5bc%23%5d

which is basically "answers:0 [c#]" and switch to the "newest" tab, returns questions starting nine hours ago and it includes questions with answers:

[image]

Comment: [status-norepro] for me.  Are you ignoring the C# tag?

Comment: No, not ignored, but it is a favorite.  That causes the flesh tone background in the hits above.  If I do the same search in a different browser without my SO login it show the same first three hits now from fifteen hours ago and has the banner bar "Welcome to Q&A ..." so it is seems unrelated to my account and is still reproducible here, albeit staler.

Comment: Partly reproducible for me, sorting is correctly and the newest question is 36 minutes old...*but* the first and third question does have an answer.

Comment: Can you still get this behavior? The 9 hours behind sounds very odd - we haven't had indexing issues in some time.  The answers on the top few can happen, since we index every 15 minutes (30 at most - if there's a build in-between), and if an answer is added in the last 15 minutes, you may see that result.

Comment: @Nick: This problem was confined to that day; I haven't seen it since.  But judging from the upvotes, others some could repro it on that day.  The tag [status-nonrepro] is fine.  It was a real phenomenon for me but it was a transient problem.

Comment: @Rick - I misread the dates, **May** 12th (I read yesterday) we did have a build issue with lucene on certain servers (app pools not *actually* dying), this was an issue then - which should have been resolved that night, making this [status-completed].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a build-related issue on this day where some app domains just didn't want to die - even when the web sites were stopped in IIS, causing some indexing overlap which caused quite a few issues on certain web servers.

In our setup users are sticky mapped to a web server, so if you mapped to one having issues, you would have seen greatly lagged indexes, the 9 hours you see in the screenshot above is an example.

We resolved this and added a few more safeguards around so hopefully the prolonged overlapping app domains won't cause issues again (though *they* shouldn't have happened in the first place...)